# Pegando o Location de um POST

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

Estou utilizando o método `HttpRequestHeader` para efetuar requisições (`GET` e `POST`), porém estou necessitando pegar o parâmetro `Location` da resposta de um `POST` e não estou conseguindo evoluir. Tem um exemplo da minha requisição abaixo:

```
url = "https://www.google.com"
        req = HttpWebRequest.Create(url)
        req.Method = "POST"
        req.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, sessao)
        req.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "pt-BR")
        req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0"
        req.Referer = "www.google.com.br"
        req.ContentType = " multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------24708330210100"
        req.ContentLength = postData.Length

        Dim swRequestWriter As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream())
        swRequestWriter.Write(postData)
        swRequestWriter.Close()

        Dim srResponseReader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF7)

        html = srResponseReader.ReadToEnd().Trim
```

Lembrando-se que os endereços são fictícios, gostaria de uma ajuda urgente.

Answer (score 2):

Acho que pegar o [`Header`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webresponse.headers?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netcore-3.1#System_Net_WebResponse_Headers) resolve o que você precisa. Substitua o final do seu código por algo assim:

```
using var response = req.GetResponse()) ;
var location = response.Headers["Location"];
using var srResponseReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()));
html = srResponseReader.ReadToEnd();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ASP.NET/GetLocation.cs).

Answer (score 1):

Acho que vc tem que pegar e verificar o `Header`

```
HttpWebResponse response = myRequest.GetResponse();

// verifica se existe o location
if( response.Headers["Location"] == null ) {    
}
else{
}
```